# How to respawn enemy in processing

Tags: javascript, processing

I'm making this game for a school project,  and we have this enemy that lunges at you, and explodes,  if you are within the radius of the explosion you'll respawn and the enemy gets destroyed and wont respawn.

We want that if you have been respawned the enemy also respawns

```
class Suicidebot{     
  float x, y, radius;
  int clr;
  float xVelocity;

  //float topPolice, rightPolice, bottomPolice, leftPolice;
  float startingX;

  boolean movement;
  int timer, timer2;

  boolean isExploded, startExploding;

  void init(float xInput, float yInput, float radiusInput1, float radiusInput2) {
    x = xInput;
    y = yInput;
    radius = radiusInput1;
    radius = radiusInput2;

    clr = color(0,255,255);
    xVelocity = 5;
    startingX = x;
    movement = false;

    timer = 0;
    isExploded = false;
    timer2 = 0;
    startExploding = false;
  }

  void update(Player player) {
    if(!isExploded) {
      movement();

      if (player.x > x - 300){
        movement = true;
      } else {
        movement = false;
      }

     if(timer > 40){
       colourSuicidebot(255,0,0);
       xVelocity = 0;
       timer = 0;
       startExploding = true;
     }

     if(startExploding == true){
       timer2+= 2;
       radius +=8;
     }

     if(timer2 >= 60){
       isExploded = true;
     }

     if(player.rightHitbox > x - radius/2 && player.leftHitbox < x +radius/2 && player.bottomHitbox > y - radius /2&& player.topHitbox < y +radius/2){
        player.init(player.xStart, player.yStart);
         isExploded = true;
      }

      if(theCamera.cameraToggle){
        x += theCamera.cameraMove;
        startingX += theCamera.cameraMove;
      }  
    } 
  }

  void movement(){
    if (movement == true){
        if(!isExploded) {
          timer++;
        }
        x -= xVelocity;
    }
  }

  void colourSuicidebot(int kleur1, int kleur2, int kleur3) {
    clr = color(kleur1, kleur2, kleur3);
  }

  void draw() {
    if(!isExploded) {
      fill(clr);
      ellipse(x,y,radius, radius);
    }
  }

}
```

if i delete the if(!isExploded) in the draw, it'll just keep growing and wont destroy itself.

So far i have tried several things to make the enemy respawn, but so far not good.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)- not your whole project, but not a disconnected snippet like this either. But if you know how to respawn your player, why can't you just do the same thing to respawn the enemy?

Comment: @roome0 If you have found a solution, you can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the `isExploded` variable when you want your enemy to respawn. You should be able to do this in the `Update` method

```
void update(Player player) {
    if(!isExploded) {
    //...
    }
    else {
        if (/*Your condition for respawning goes here*/){
            isExploded=false; // and any other respawning code
        }
    }
}
```